# elixir.bootlin doesn't work to search Linux files?

Tags: c, linux, unix, linux-kernel, kernel

I am having a wide problem dealing with linux.

I am trying to find the implementation of do_execv and sys_execv so I went to: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.12/A/ident/do_execv

and searched for `do_execv` but I got no results at all, how is that even possible? doesn't linux have such a function?

Comment: Did you mean sys_execve and do_execve?  Right here https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/exec.c#L2058

Comment: Why search doesn't work, btw you sent me a call to do_execv I don't see sys_execv implementation @stark

Answer (score 2):

No, the Linux kernel does not have a 'do_execv' symbol.

All POSIX.1 exec*() functions in the standard C library use either the `execve` or `execveat` syscalls, defined in [fs/exec.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.12/source/fs/exec.c).

Two of the helper functions in that file that these syscalls use, are named `do_execve` and `do_execveat`; note that they take a `struct filename` instead of an userspace string as a parameter.

If you search for `sys_execve` – the function implementing the syscall –, it will not find the syscall definition in fs/exec.c, because usually syscalls are defined using a macro `SYSCALL_DEFINEn(name, ...)`, where `n` is the number of parameters, and the defined function name will be `sys_name`.  So, for syscalls, you usually search for both the sys_*name* symbol, as well as the syscall name only but check that the line it occurs on begins with `SYSCALL_DEFINE`.

Comment: you are wrong, I just opened a file and it had do_exec...